# Optimize for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

I have three matrices, `A` is 2 by 3, `B` is 2 by 5 and `Index` is 3 by 5.

```
A = [1,3,5;2,4,6];
B = [5,3,3,5,3;6,4,4,6,4];
Index = logical([0,0,0,0,1;0,1,1,0,0;1,0,0,1,0]);
```

I am trying to see if each column vector in B matches with the correct column vector in `A` found by the index. The code I have is below.

```
error = 0;
for i = 1:size(B,2)
    if A(:,Index(:,i)) ~= B(:,i)
        error = error + 1;
    end
end
```

`error` will be 1 at the end of this loop because the last column in `B` should've been [1;2]. My problem is for very large(10^6) length of `B` and `Index`, this becomes very slow. Is there a way I can avoid the for loop or am I doomed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the indexed matrix upfront with `A*Index` and then test the two matrices directly:

```matlab
>> error = sum(max(A*Index ~= B))

error =

     1
```

---

#### Details

Broken down, `A*Index` generates the indexed matrix:

```matlab
>> A*Index

ans =

     5     3     3     5     1
     6     4     4     6     2
```

Which can then be compared directly with `B`:

```matlab
>> A*Index ~= B

ans =

  2×5 logical array

   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   1
```

---

#### Timings

With 10 million indexes, R2021a Online runs the vectorized version in ~1 sec vs ~100 sec for the loop:

```matlab
>> B = repmat(B, 1, 1e7);
>> Index = repmat(Index, 1, 1e7);
```

```matlab
>> tic
   error = sum(max(A*Index ~= B));
   toc

Elapsed time is 0.952846 seconds.
```

```matlab
>> tic
   error = 0
   for i = 1:size(B,2)
       if A(:,Index(:,i)) ~= B(:,i)
           error = error + 1;
       end               
   end                           
   toc

Elapsed time is 98.666943 seconds.
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? There’s a double indirection in the indexing, but I’m still surprised it would take this long to run. The vectorized solution uses a lot more memory, and so could be suspected to be slower.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm using R2021a Online. It was sluggish/crashing a lot on me last night, so I guess something was wrong. I tried it again just now and it was faster on both counts.